# How to release resources of std::map and std::unordered_map manually as std::vector in C++ 11 and higher

Tags: c++

Assume we have a vector `std::vector<int> v` and let's assume that some resources are allocated to it. To my knowledge, `v.clear()` and `v.shrink_to_fit()` releases all resources allocated to `v`. I am wondering if there exist similar operations for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` that release all resources manually. I can only find a member function `clear()` for these two templates. Can someone explain why there is no `shrink_to_fit()` for the latter two templates?

Comment: like vectors the function is clear: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear
But if the values are raw pointers, then u need to iterate the map and delete them manually.

Comment: imo shrink doesn't really make sense to node-based container.

Comment: Note that those vector functions don't necessarily release any underlying storage (and usually don't).

Comment: if you want, (and can) you can destruct the container, which would probably always release all resource.

Comment: [Edited] There is no `shrink_to_fit` simply because memory in `map` is not allocated like `vector`. `vector` allocates the memory in "blocks" of a certain size, that's why such a function is required to free the "unused" (if any) memory of the last block (tries to make `capacity` same as `size`). But in case of `map`, you internally have a binary search tree (R-B tree to be precise). In it nodes are created and inserted. It always take only the memory that is required. `map` doesn't "pre-allocate" memory like `vector`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `shrink_to_fit()` in `std::map`, because it would be useless.

In `std::vector`, to ensure amortized constant insertion time required by standard, implementation can allocate more memory than is currently necessary for future storage (so that it doesn't have to reallocate everything each `push_back()`). Most implementations allocate `2*size()` if current `capacity()` would be exceeded.

`shrink_to_fit()` asks to release that extra memory to make `size() == capacity()` (but it's not guaranteed that this will actually happen).

Now, `std::map` is usually implemented as a red-black tree. Adding an element into such structure is just creating new node and a bit of pointer magic. It will not involve reallocation of other nodes and you cannot speed it up by pre-allocating some memory. `shrink_to_fit()` doesn't make sense, because there is nothing to shrink.

Update after [dewaffled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074081/dewaffled)'s comment: For `std::unordered_map` there's a [`rehash()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/rehash) method which may decrease size of hash table by recalculating it, but similarly to `shrink_to_fit()` it's not a guaranteed result.

Comment: For `unordered_map` there is [rehash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/rehash) method to update number of allocated buckets after `clear` which may help, but it is not required to reduce number of buckets by the standard. So, there is no guaranteed way to completely shrink it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you're talking about dynamic maps; the shrink_to_fit() wouldn't make sense because the map is only as big as its linked elements. My understanding is that there isn't 'empty' nodes for a map, like you could have empty fields in a vector.